# How to make a custom field on NonStock Item screen select values from a new DAC for custom table?

Tags: acumatica

I've been able to add the new DAC for our custom ItemBaseDocument table through the customizatio project interface.  Unfortunately, I am unable to reference the new DAC when I make one of our custom fields have a PXSelector that is supposed to select from the new DAC.

I get an error that states the following:
The type or namespace name 'ItemBaseDocument' could not be found

Comment: The error occurs when I attempt to publish

Comment: using DocCenter;

[PXDBString(50, IsUnicode = true)]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Document Number", Visibility = PXUIVisibility.SelectorVisible)]
[PXSelector(
typeof(ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentCode),
typeof(ItemBaseDocument.baseDocumentShortDescription))]

Comment: I also had to remove the control from the screen, save and publish...and then add the control back to the screen again for it to work.

Comment: The strange thing on the selector lookup screen is that the ShortDescription field is the first column and the BaseDocumentCode is the last column.  Anyone have an idea as to why that would be?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following section from the T200 guide (Acumatica Framework Fundamentals) available at Acumatica University:

[image]